Belief in Teshuvah being a prerequisite
Somebody told me that the Rambam says that belief in the idea of Teshuvah is a prerequisite to Teshuvah itself. Can anyone source this?

אֵין יוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים וְלֹא הַחַטָּאת וְלֹא הָאָשָׁם מְכַפְּרִין אֶלָּא עַל הַשָּׁבִים הַמַּאֲמִינִים בְּכַפָּרָתָן. אֲבָל הַמְבַעֵט בָּהֶן אֵינָן מְכַפְּרִין בּוֹ. כֵּיצַד. הָיָה מְבַעֵט וְהֵבִיא חַטָּאתוֹ אוֹ אֲשָׁמוֹ וְהוּא אוֹמֵר אוֹ מְחַשֵּׁב בְּלִבּוֹ שֶׁאֵין אֵלּוּ מְכַפְּרִין. אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁקָּרְבוּ כְּמִצְוָתָן לֹא נִתְכַּפֵּר לוֹ וּכְשֶׁיַּחֲזֹר בִּתְשׁוּבָה מִבְּעִיטָתוֹ צָרִיךְ לְהָבִיא חַטָּאתוֹ וַאֲשָׁמוֹ. וְכֵן הַמְבַעֵט בְּיוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים אֵין יוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים מְכַפֵּר עָלָיו. לְפִיכָךְ אִם נִתְחַיֵּב בְּאָשָׁם תָּלוּי וְעָבַר עָלָיו יוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים וְהוּא מְבַעֵט בּוֹ הֲרֵי זֶה לֹא נִתְכַּפֵּר לוֹ וּכְשֶׁיַּחֲזֹר בִּתְשׁוּבָה אַחַר יוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים חַיָּב לְהָבִיא כָּל אָשָׁם תָּלוּי שֶׁהָיָה חַיָּב בּוֹ:
Yom Kippur, sin-offerings and guilt-offerings do not generate atonement unless one repents and believes in the atonement they grant. If, however, one rebels against them, they do not generate atonement for him.What is implied? A person was in a state of rebellion, but brought a sin-offering or a guilt-offering, saying or thinking in his heart that these will not generate atonement. Accordingly, even though they were offered as commanded, they do not generate atonement for him. When he repents from his rebellion, he must bring another sin-offering and/or guilt-offering. Similarly, when one is in a state of rebellion on Yom Kippur, Yom Kippur does not atone for him. Therefore if he was obligated to bring a tentative guilt-offering and Yom Kippur passed while he was in a state of rebellion, Yom Kippur does not generate atonement for him. When he repents after Yom Kippur, he is obligated to bring all the tentative guilt-offerings for which he is liable (Mishneh Torah, Hilchot Shegagot 3:10).

Rambam here isn’t (directly) talking about belief in teshuvah, rather about belief in the power of Yom Kippur and korbanot to effect atonement.

@JoelK I think it’s a pretty straightforward inference though.
